# Cytoscape.js - why do old graphs/instances disappear when new instances are added programmatically?

Tags: javascript, dom, cytoscape.js

I've created a variation of the "multiple instances" example (https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/310dca83ba6970812dd0/) where, instead of adding all instances at the beginning, a new DIV container and a cytoscape instance is added every time you click on the document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
    <title>Multiple instances</title>
    <script src="https://js.cytoscape.org/js/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var elesJson = {
      nodes: [
          { data: { id: 'a', foo: 3, bar: 5, baz: 7 } },
          { data: { id: 'b', foo: 7, bar: 1, baz: 3 } },
          { data: { id: 'c', foo: 2, bar: 7, baz: 6 } },
          { data: { id: 'd', foo: 9, bar: 5, baz: 2 } },
          { data: { id: 'e', foo: 2, bar: 4, baz: 5 } }
      ],

      edges: [
          { data: { id: 'ae', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'e' } },
          { data: { id: 'ab', weight: 3, source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
          { data: { id: 'be', weight: 4, source: 'b', target: 'e' } },
          { data: { id: 'bc', weight: 5, source: 'b', target: 'c' } },
          { data: { id: 'ce', weight: 6, source: 'c', target: 'e' } },
          { data: { id: 'cd', weight: 2, source: 'c', target: 'd' } },
          { data: { id: 'de', weight: 7, source: 'd', target: 'e' } }
      ]
      };

      var count = 1;

      // add new container and cytoscape instance
      document.onclick = function () {

          var t = (count - 1) * 20;

          // first, add the container
          document.body.innerHTML += `<div id="cy${count}" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: ${t}%; width: 100%; height: 20%; z-index: 999;"></div>`

          // then, add the cytoscape instance
          cytoscape({
          container: document.getElementById(`cy${count}`),
          style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
          .selector('node')
          .css({
              'background-color': '#B3767E',
              'width': 'mapData(baz, 0, 10, 10, 40)',
              'height': 'mapData(baz, 0, 10, 10, 40)',
              'content': 'data(id)'
          })
          .selector('edge')
          .css({
              'line-color': '#F2B1BA',
              'target-arrow-color': '#F2B1BA',
              'width': 2,
              'target-arrow-shape': 'circle',
              'opacity': 0.8
          })
          .selector(':selected')
          .css({
              'background-color': 'black',
              'line-color': 'black',
              'target-arrow-color': 'black',
              'source-arrow-color': 'black',
              'opacity': 1
          })
          .selector('.faded')
          .css({
              'opacity': 0.25,
              'text-opacity': 0
          }),

          elements: elesJson,

          layout: {
          name: 'circle',
          padding: 10
          },

          ready: function(){
          // ready 1
          }
          });

          // increment
          count++;
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My expectation would be that the new instance appears below the old one, but this is not the case.

Instead, the new instance appears in the expected location, while the old instance disappears. The container of the old instance remains in the DOM.

I can't quite find an explanation for this behavior, especially as all the rest is just as in the original example. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cytoscape instances are still there, but the DOM elements those instances were attached to get replaced with new elements because you changed the entire `body.innerHTML`.

So, basically, instead of

```js
document.body.innerHTML += `<div id="cy${count}" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: ${t}%; width: 100%; height: 20%; z-index: 999;"></div>`
```

You should do

```
let newCytoscapeInstanceContainer = document.createElement('div');
newCytoscapeInstanceContainer.id = `cy${count}`;
newCytoscapeInstanceContainer.style.cssText = `position: absolute; left: 0; top: ${t}%; width: 100%; height: 20%; z-index: 999;`;
document.body.appendChild(newCytoscapeInstanceContainer);
```

Or use `cy.mount()` to bind each of the previous Cytoscape instances to the new DOM elements, but I wouldn't recommend.

Working pen - https://codepen.io/Raven0us/pen/RwraGgB